# Huge size of mongod.log file on ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, logging, ubuntu-14.04

I am running mongod 3.0.2 server on ubuntu 14.04 and on avg mongod.log file size is increased by 1G at eod , and in a week its size is up to 6 GB. As of now I don't need mongod logs of such fine level.

Is there a way to configure logging level in mongod server? so that not everything is printed in mongod.log and its size could be kept checked.

Comment: When a log file grows that rapidly, I _may_ be a a good idea to have a look into it. I suspect a lot of lines having the keyword QUERY in them. If that is the case, it is indicating that you may have severe performance problems...

Comment: Thanks Markus,
I am analyzing the mongo db logs to see why its growing so quickly. Thanks for your input!